# linq to sql with multiple aggregators

Tags: linq-to-sql, aggregate

I want to translate this simple SQL statement to linq-to-sql:

```
SELECT SUM(field1), SUM(field2)
FROM TableName
```

The closest linq-to-sql is (i think) using the group by clause:

```
from tbl in TableName
group tbl by (1) into g
select new{ value1= g.Sum(p => p.field1), value2 = g.Sum(p => p.field2)};
```

As this does not produce the expected outcome, what must be changed??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *should* produce the same result. In what way does it not?

Comment: You 're right!! In deed it produces the correct result set!! ...where was i when debugged??hhhmmmm....

Answer (score 0):

You want it without the group by.
The only way I can think of is this:

```
var result =  new {value1 = Table1.Sum(a => a.field1), value2 = Table1.Sum(a => a.field2)};
```

Which is a bit of a bummer as it emits 2 separate queries.

You can use linqpad: http://www.linqpad.net/ to find out what sql your linq is emitting.

Comment: In my case i cannot use this approach because the actual statement is far more complicated and thus would raise performance issues. But thanks very much, after all it's good to know!